# Variable text in sql to C#

Tags: c#, sql

I have this:

```
public DataSet HopDongTheoNhaCungCap(string MaNCC)
        {
            return db.MyExcuteSQL("SELECT MaHD, TenHD, ThoiHan, NCC from HopDongCungCap as c where c.NCC= 'NCC_01'", CommandType.Text, null);                    
        }
```

And now I want to change to:

```
public DataSet HopDongTheoNhaCungCap(string MaNCC)
        {
            return db.MyExcuteSQL("SELECT MaHD, TenHD, ThoiHan, NCC from HopDongCungCap as c where c.NCC= " + MaNCC, CommandType.Text, null);                    
        }
```

but when I update value for MaNCC example MaNCC = "NCC_01", 
it turn

```
SELECT MaHD, TenHD, ThoiHan, NCC from HopDongCungCap as c where c.NCC= NCC_01"
```

NCC_01 here is a column not a text
please help me

Comment: Try to use Parameterized sql instead which database are you using??

Comment: You are missing the single quotes around the value.

Comment: `"And now I want to change to"` - No you don't.  That's a SQL injection vulnerability.  Use query parameters.

Comment: This code is vulnerable to SQL injection. This is why you should at the very least use parameters, and the best course would be to use an ORM (object relational modeler) like Entity Framework, NHibernate, or Linq2sql

Comment: thanks for your help, Im missing the single quotes around the value!!!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, parameterized is the way to go.  However, in answer to your direct question, the problem is that in your second set of code you don't put quotes around the string variable.  It should be

```
        return db.MyExcuteSQL("SELECT MaHD, TenHD, ThoiHan, NCC from HopDongCungCap as c where c.NCC= '" + MaNCC + "'", CommandType.Text, null);
```

with quotes around the variable you're adding.

Comment: @Cuong If this answer solved your problem, (are you SURE sure you don't want parameterized queries?), please mark it as accepted.  Thanks!

Comment: you mean use store procedure?

Comment: You don't have to use a stored procedure to use a parameterized query, but you can. Here's a whole article about it.  The quotes will solve the problem if you aren't going to do this in production, but  it is far better practice to use parameterized.  http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/

Comment: hmm...cause i've use three layer so i cant do that thing like:
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(s);  
cmd.Parameters.Add("@email", email); 
can you give me an example with the code above @@

Answer (score 0):

I've use

```
return db.MyExcuteSQL("spHopDongTheoNhaCungCap", CommandType.StoredProcedure, new SqlParameter("@MaNCC",MaNCC));
```

this my sp:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spHopDongTheoNhaCungCap]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    (@MaNCC NVARCHAR(50) )
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT MaHD, TenHD, ThoiHan, NCC from HopDongCungCap as c where c.NCC=@MaNCC
END
```

and this's my problem

```
Procedure or function 'spHopDongTheoNhaCungCap' expects parameter '@MaNCC', which was not supplied.
```

Note that im using threelayer so i dont know how to do something like this:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(...);
```

Comment: Hello, since this isn't an answer, would you edit your question and post your updates there..?

Comment: Also, you do not need to put "@" sign in C# Take a look at this: http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter